# Any reason for why data won't be stored in this struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, malloc

I'm storing data in a struct and want to know why it's not being stored in the struct properly. I've check that the `sscanf` works properly by scanning it into variables instead and printing those. But as soon as I try to store it in this struct it doesn't work.

So I printed the struct and it shows `Location`, `direction` and `name` to be `NULL` as that's their default value and length is 0.

```
Ship *newShip = (Ship*)malloc(sizeof(Ship));
sscanf(line, "%s %s %d %[^\n]", newShip->location, newShip->direction,
       &newShip->length, newShip->name);    
printf("\nShip %d: \n\tLocation: %s \n\tDirection: %s \n\tLength: %d \n\tName: %s\n",
       shipNum, newShip->location, newShip->direction, newShip->length, newShip->name);
shipNum++;
```

Edit The struct used follows:

```
typedef struct {
    char *location;                          
    char *direction;                        
    int length;                             
    char *name;                             
} Ship;
```

Edit: Example of string being formatted.

```
"D4 E 3 NullByte Sub"
```

Ship num was just a count I was using to track what ship number I was printing.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: You don’t check the return value of `sscanf` to know if it actually did anything. Also please provide a [mcve] with input so we know exactly what the full code is. There’s no definition for `Ship` so many things could be wrong.

Comment: Updated adding the string being processed and the struct.

Comment: So you don’t allocate memory for the location or direction? That’s undefined behavior. Allocate space for them, otherwise nothing can be stored.

Comment: @M.M: the ` %[^\n]` conversion specifier will store the rest of the line into whatever `newShip->name` points to, stopping before the newline if any. The format is fine as long as there is at least one non blank character after the number, but `newShip->name` is uninitialized.

Comment: @Argon: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointers inside the struct is not pointing to a valid memory location which leads to undefined behavior.

Allocate memory for the struct members `location,direction,name.`

Eg:

```
Ship* newShip = malloc(sizeof(Ship));
newShip->location=malloc(size);
newShip->direction=malloc(size);
newShip->name=malloc(size);
```

size denotes the size of memory for each struct member.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure contains pointers for the strings, not arrays. When you allocate it with `malloc()`, you must initialize these pointers to some allocate memory for `sscanf()` to store to. As posted, the code has undefined behavior. Furthermore, you should check for allocation failure and also verify the number of conversions returned by `sscanf()` to detect invalid input.

If your C library supports a common extension, the `m` allocation modifier, you could write this:

```c
typedef struct {
    char *location;
    char *direction;
    int length;
    char *name;
} Ship;

Ship *create_ship(const char *line) {
    Ship *newShip = calloc(sizeof(Ship), 1);
    if (newShip) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%ms %ms %d %m[^\n]", &newShip->location,
                   &newShip->direction, &newShip->length, &newShip->name) == 4)) {
            printf("\nShip %d:\n\tLocation: %s\n\tDirection: %s\n"
                   "\tLength: %d\n\tName: %s\n", shipNum, newShip->location, 
                   newShip->direction, newShip->length, newShip->name);
        } else {
            /* format error */
            free(newShip->location);
            free(newShip->direction);
            free(newShip);
            newShip = NULL;
        }
    }
    return newShip;
}
```

For a simpler and more portable approach you could define the string fields in the `Ship` as arrays of `char` and use:

```c
typedef struct {
    char location[20];
    char direction[4];
    int length;
    char name[50];
} Ship;

Ship *create_ship(const char *line) {
    Ship *newShip = calloc(sizeof(Ship), 1);
    if (newShip) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%19s %3s %d %49[^\n]", newShip->location,
                   newShip->direction, &newShip->length, newShip->name) == 4)) {
            printf("\nShip %d:\n\tLocation: %s\n\tDirection: %s\n"
                   "\tLength: %d\n\tName: %s\n", shipNum, newShip->location, 
                   newShip->direction, newShip->length, newShip->name);
        } else {
            /* format error */
            free(newShip);
            newShip = NULL;
        }
    }
    return newShip;
}
```